# How to get chapter details & metadata info. from .m4b file stored in device ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, metadata

I used below code. But not giving chapters details & metadata info like track no. etc from `.m4b` file.

Here tried to get `chapterMetaDataGroup` information from file url using `AVURLAsset`.It seems working when url is `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` correctly. But when using file url from device, not getting metadata correctly.

```
    var chapterList: [AnyHashable]? = nil
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: file, options: nil)
    let locales = asset.availableChapterLocales
    let locale = locales.last as NSLocale?

    if locale != nil
    {
        chapterList = asset.chapterMetadataGroups(withTitleLocale: locale as! Locale, containingItemsWithCommonKeys: nil)
        print(chapterList)
    }
```

Comment: You are retrieving `Locals` not chapter. Read here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/1388228-availablechapterlocales.

Comment: without using Locale, how is it possible to retrieve chapters details avaialble?Can you share code?

Comment: Here is solution - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/presenting_chapter_markers

Comment: Thanks for Help! But i found above my code working correct also when i tried with another .m4b file which have chapters in it.